# spring unable to inject 'java.lang.Class

Tags: java, spring

I created a stack class as below my intention is to initialize the size of the elements of type E in stack.

How should be the Class be injected thorugh spring.

But spring is throwing error as below, How should i fix this problem ?

```
@Service
public class Stack<E> {

    int MAX_SIZE = 15;

    E[] elements;



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Stack(Class<E> clazz) {
        elements = (E[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, MAX_SIZE);
    }

    volatile int i;

    public void push(E e) throws InterruptedException {
        while (i > MAX_SIZE) {
            Thread.currentThread().wait();
        }
        elements[i++] = e;
        Thread.currentThread().notifyAll();
    }

    public E pop() throws InterruptedException {
        while (i < 0) {
            Thread.currentThread().wait();
        }
        Thread.currentThread().notifyAll();
        return elements[i--];
    }

}
```

**Parameter 0 of constructor in Stack required a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' that could not be found.**

Comment: Can you add your bean configuration file.

Comment: adding @Autowired
 java.lang.Class<E> clazz; causing null pointer exception. How to inject though constructor ?

Comment: Why do you reinvent the wheel? Use a LinkedBlockingDeque. BTW, even if you really want your own implementation, it should not extend Thread, and it should not need an Class as argument. Just use an Object[] to store the elements.

Comment: @JB Nizet if i define as object how shall i would be generic ?

Comment: The same way you're doing now, with an additional cast to E in the pop() method.

Comment: yes thats correct but want to know how should constructor inject the Class  below dosen't work even                                                                         @Autowired
 java.lang.Class<E> clazz;
 
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 Stack() {
  elements = (E[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, MAX_SIZE);
 }   it seems that constructor is being called first before injecting the bean is being injected. so hence it would be necessary to use some aware implementation.

Comment: And what I'm saying that you don't need any Class argument in the first place, which makes your problem disappear. That shouldn't even be a Spring bean anyway.

Comment: @JB Nizet I understand the Object solution but just thinking that there is some way to this kind of problem scenario.

Comment: There are ways of course. How did you declare your bean in the first place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137276/discussion-between-curious-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the default Java Stack implementation.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: I'm just experimenting with creation of generic array with spring.

Answer (score 0):

include a 0 parameter constructor

```
public Stack(){

}
```